# Create square NSButton programmatically swift

Tags: swift, nsbutton

There's my code:

```
var newBut = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 30, height: 30))
newBut.title = "press me!"
self.view.addSubview(newBut)
```

But it creates the button that differs from square button. It's darker and has smh like a shadow. I'm looking for a way to change its appearance to copy the square button style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the [`bezelStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/NSBezelStyle) of your NSButton to `SmallSquareBezelStyle`.

```
newBut.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.SmallSquareBezelStyle
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 4** (Xcode 9) "*bezelStyle*" is now "*BezelStyle*".

Note that, *BezelStyle* no longer has a member "*SmallSquareBezelStyle*". *BezelStyle* is a "UInt".

Per Apple "**NSButton.BezelStyle**" documentation, BezelStyle can be:

- circular
- disclosure
- helpButton
- inLine
- recessed
- regularSquare
- roundRect
- rounded
- roundedDisclosure
- shadowlessSquare
- smallSquare
- textureRounded, and
- texturedSquare

It seems that you were looking at one of the "square" button cases.